# How to debug H264 DirectShow filter?

Tags: windows, directshow, h.264, decoder

I'm developping a h264 directshow filter.

I have a valid hardware source which outputs NAL units properly.
I have a DirectShow filter which advertises h264 and successfully connects to the default windows 7 decoder microsoft dtv-dvd video decoder.

When I connect a renderer to the decoder, the renderer doesn't get any packets, so I assume that the decoder fails to decode my packets properly.

[ h264 Source ] -> [ dtv-dvd decoder ] -> [ enhanced video renderer ]

Is there any way for me to check where the microsoft decoder fails?

Any other info could be helpful

Comment: More likely is that decoder input is invalid, and you need to review what you are delivering off the output pin.

Answer (score 3):

The difficulty you have is that you do not have the code for the dtv-dvd decoder, making it somewhat of a black-box in the pipeline. The fact that your h264 Source can connect to the dtv-dvd decoder means you are off to a good start regarding media format negotiation. To get a better view of what is going wrong I suggest that you swap out the dtv-dvd decoder with one for which you have the source code and then debug your pipeline using GraphEdit or one of the similar tools.  I have been doing the same sort of development and have found that once I got the h264 pipeline working properly with one decoder filter, it has generally worked properly with other h264 decoders.

Here are a few options which include source code:

- [Intel Media SDK 2012](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/vcsource-tools-media-sdk/) includes a sample h264 decoder filter.
- If you have an Nvidia GPU, you can try out this open source [CUDA Decode Filter](http://code.google.com/p/cuda-decode-filter/)

Also, I have found the dtv-dvd filter to be a little finicky. It may be helpful to test using one of the following decoder filters available in binary form :

- Nanocosmos has a very nice "[AVC/h264 decoder Decoder SDK](http://www.nanocosmos.de/v3/order/demo.php)" based on directshow. (Free Eval)
- "[CoreCodec's CoreAVC](http://www.corecodec.com/products/coreavc)" includes one of the fastest h264 decoders supporting CUDA and DXVA (Commercial - costs $12.95)
- MainConcept's h264 decoder filter is available as part of their "[MainConcept Showcase](http://www.mainconcept.com/products/sdks/others/showcase.html)" (Free Eval)

Comment: I would also like to add to this the per-today excellent LAV Filters package, which is a continuation or rather re-imagination of the ffdshow filters project, where DirectShow filters are built from libavformat and libavcodec and related, traditionally FFMpeg-affiliated, libraries. It has a H.264 splitter and decoder (name of filter is "LAV Video Decoder") which fit to a H.264 capture pin of e.g. media source filter.